# Where is information about subscriptions stored in the database in woocomerce subscription?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The fact is that the documentation states

```
subscription data will be stored in the shop_subscription table (or wp_shop_subscription, depending on the prefix of the tables in your database).
```

None of us have a subscription to the table

[image]

I need to connect to the database using the program and get the data directly from the database, but I can't find where the users and user subscriptions are, I will be glad to help, thank you.  it is written that subscriptions in shop_subscription are located but I do not have such a table

Woocommerce 7.9.0
subscription to woocommerce 5.2.0

Comment: @Logicgates Could you give me an example SQL query to get a subscription string with user id, user subscriptions (id and so on)? I can only use the user id in the request, also here is a list of all my tables in the database 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RINCODER/fishbot_majestik/main/tables.txt

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using mysql or mariaDB as a database. You can try to execute

`SHOW TABLES;`

in order to see what are the available tables in your database.